# Join equivalence - Parentheses overload

Tags: mysql, sql

On a SQL query, is

```
FROM (a LEFT JOIN b ON <cond>) LEFT JOIN c ON <cond>
```

equivalent to

```
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON <cond> LEFT JOIN c ON <cond>
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are the same.

In both `A` is left joined to `B` and the resulting virtual table is left joined onto `C`.

You might use paranetheses to achieve something like this

```
FROM (a LEFT JOIN b ON <cond>) LEFT JOIN (c INNER JOIN d ON <cond>) ON <cond>
```

Although it is actually the placement of the `ON` clause not the parentheses that is important.